# Why wouldn't dnsmasq respond to a client?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, dnsmasq

I discovered recently an issue on a otherwise working server. It was updated in the past months so there may have been changed between the time when "everything was fine" and today.

This server hosts a `dnsmasq` server which provides both DHCP and DNS services to:

- the server itself
- a set of containers running on this server (each with its own IP received from this `dnsmasq`)
- clients in the LAN (wired, wireless)

I realized today that when I reboot the server:

- a client cannot resolve names anymore (`Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.` on a Windows box for instance)
- an `nginx` server in one of the containers crashes at startup, not being able to resolve a name

The strange points:

- `dnsmasq` does run on the server and resolves names for that server (`# ping google.com` works fine from within the server)
- restarting `dnsmasq` fixes all the issues: all clients can now resolve names
- at least for containers, the fact that they have an IP address means that `dnsmasq` served it to them, together with the DNS server information (= itself).

My main problem is: **why would a restart of `dnsmasq` fix the lack of resolution the clients?** It is working for the server, the traffic between the clients and the server is not obstructed (even if it was, it is not the restart of `dnsmasq` which would have solved that).

The only idea I have is that, maybe, when `dnsmasq` is starting all the interfaces are not available yet. This is quite far fetched but maybe. Is there a way to check which interfaces `dnsmasq` is bound to? (`netstat` or `lsof` will just show `*.53` so it does not help)

The idea above does not seem correct for another reason: the containers receive their IP from `dnsmasq`, so since they have one, `dnsmasq` must have bound to their interface.

Comment: You said "dnsmasq does run on the server and resolves names for that server (# ping google.com works fine from within the server)", does the server use a different nameserver in resolv.conf?

Comment: @MikeMarseglia: no, it is `nameserver 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Nothing in dnsmasq logs? When it fails, did you try a DNS query with `dig` and how it behaves? If `netstat` shows `*:53` that should mean all interfaces